# Trying to install fast qc in R

Tags: r, windows, rna-seq

I'm trying to install fastqc in R to construct a RNA-Seq analysis pipeline, I've tried everything and when I try to install it using "install.packages("fastqc")" I get the following error message:

"Warning in install.packages :package ‘fastqc’ is not available (for R version 3.5.0)"

Any help is appreciated, thanks in advance.

Comment: You probably want `fastqcr` package: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/fastqcr/fastqcr.pdf

Comment: It's also time to update R, version 3.5.0 is dated 2018-04-23.

Comment: I have updated and I'm still having the problem, can an RNA-seq pipeline only be done on unix? as fastqcr seems to be used after you have the fastqc files whereas as i only have the fastq files